# Display posts of current category in Jekyll blog

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I want to display posts of current category in Jekyll blog. So, I wrote the code like following.

```
<div class="side-left col-sm-4 col-md-4">
  {% for category in site.categories %}
    {% if page.categories == category.first %}
    <h3 class="lead"> {{ category | first }} </h3><hr>
    <ul>
      {% for post in category[1] limits:5 %}
      <li><a href="{{ post.url }}" style="color:whitesmoke;"> {{ post.title | truncate:40 }}</a></li>
      {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But when I renewed the blog, nothing occurred on a sidebar. For examination, I wrote {{ page.categories }} {{ category.first }} between line 2 and 3. And the sidebar show me

A A A B A C A D

What is problem and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

{{ category }} is a string and not an array, so when you write {{ category.first }} you get first letter of the string ;).